# List of discovered and failed tests in VS Code

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to get a list of discovered tests and failed tests in VS Code after running tests.

I'm reading VS Code's documentation and googling around, but I've got nothing so far.

I use pytest for testing and there is `--collect-only` option, but I'd like some GUI so that I could save some time.

What I'm thinking is something like in pycharm. For example:

[image: test_list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can view the test output by clicking on the test results in the status bar or you can look at the code lenses on your tests. Otherwise adding such a view is an [open feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/193) which you can leave a  reaction on to vote up its priority.